# crackeling sound issue

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card

Alright so has this sound problem that has just recently resurfaced it ugly head.  I never did figure out what the problem was before, it just randomly disapeared when i started overclocking. Drove me crazy a year ago and its starting yet again

for example i can be in a web page and when i scroll down the sound crackles, or if i move my mouse really fast the sound crackles.  Doesn't matter if its a game, youtube, or Songbird.  doesn't matter on which hard drive its on, I tried different drives(i have 5 to choose).  also doesnt matter what line, speakers headphones, or optical out(i have 5.1 headphones with digital connection, tried both digital connections)
this has nothing at all to do with cables, or headphones.  the music acutally slows down when it crackles especially when changing windows and small quick things like that.

Now i have confirmed this has nothing to do with software.  I installed another partition with windows and linux and the same issue was there.  Also this has nothing to do with my sound card because there is no difference between using the onboard sound and a sound card I went and got just becuase of this problem([HT Omega if it matters](http://www.htomega.com/rgboard/view.php?bbs_id=new_products&doc_num=8)

here are the rough specs of my system

Asus p5k-e wifi-ap(wifi disabled)
Intel Q6600 Core2Quad overclocked to bout 3.2ghz now i think and watercooled.
6gb of Crucial Basillstix.  i had 8gb but 2 sticks died 2 weeks ago, and i happen to have a spare from the last time i rma'd it a year ago.  worst ram ever, probably my issue.    also i have 6 because i reguularily need more than 4.
main hd WD 640gb Black
secondary's various 500gb WD or hitachi, plus a 1.5tb samsung(i think.  the ones with filmware issues, never fixed it because its just a backup drive)

powersupply 850w Consair
Nvidia 9800gtx and 9600gt running 3 22in monitors.

Any thoughts on what this may be?  drives me crazy, sounds crackeling as I type right now and makes listening to music irritating and gaming impossible.  I have tried changing my clock settings with no change...  I have checked my ram and all 3 current sticks are fine anthough i really want a reason to change them. (and makeing it an even 2 sticks makes no difference)

Thank You.

Comment: so much for formatting.....

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this on a few older computers, but not for many years.

It is simply down to interference - it can be external (lights, mobile phones, anything wireless etc.) but it can also be internal (such as what I think is happening in your case).

Unfortunately I don't think there is anything you can do. I would of said try another sound card - but you already have.

Also, I have never got it to work - but I have heard a few people having success by putting a grounding loop around the speaker cable.

Comment: Last time this happened i completly took apart my computer and changed cases, no change. also tested it outside of the case. 
I do have cathodes but turning them off made no difference, and unplugging fans did nothing  the only thing that fixed it before was overclocking.. but thats not being being so successful this time.

Comment: @WalterJ89 - it isn't likely to be the case itself, more likely other components such as features on the motherboard, other add-ons, or anything wireless - sorry it didn't help/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it(I think)

Problem was my ram timing.  I loosened them up due to BSOD's on the normal settings So by Default it is supposed to be 800mhz 4-4-4-12 at 2.0v and i moved it to 1000mhz - 5-5-5-15 at 2.0v(or 14 i dont remember, if you do the math it turns out to be exactly the same throughput,  also 800mhz at those timings was really slow). bsod's went away and system was stable but i guess the audio problem doesn't start right away.

My motherboard 'AUTO' setting wants to change settings to 5-5-5-15 800mhz at 1.8 or 1.7v  which burns out the ram after 2 months(and 4 month of slowly getting worse, random bsod's)

So the Moral, Never Ever get Crucial basillstix on sale, ever. I have 2 stick i'm waiting on an RMA and the last 2 or 3 are on thier way out. so i'm stuck with a trade off of random BSOD's or irritating audio studdering

Thanks